# Separate Flask app users using the same function

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm creating an app that allows users to get weather events sent directly to their access control/intrusion system. It works so far, but I need to allow multiple people with different system locations to request data based on their location. I have a function that takes the address and requests the weather alerts then sends them via API to the system no problem. How do I allow for that function to be accessed and ran by multiple users without causing an issue? If I use something like Flask-login will it allow separate users to use this function at the same time?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Shared application logic should be fine. Multiple people using it at the same time should be fine. Are you having a specific issue? If so, please share the code so that we can read it and troubleshoot. It seems like what you're asking about is a basic aspect of most dynamic websites regardless of programming language or framework, and so I'm not clear on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm asking if flask-login handles user sessions in such a way that separate users can utilize the function at the same time or if i need to use a multi-threading method or something along those lines if flask-login is not enough

Comment: Honestly, flask-login isn't at all relevant to this question. You might want to look up "flask user session security" for information on this topic. I understand your concern, but ... it shouldn't really be a concern. This is a core aspect of web apps - shared logic that delivers dynamic/individual responses. Like a shopping cart or something. What is it that keeps you from seeing someone else's shopping cart? User sessions. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#sessions

Comment: Flask-login is relevant as I'm wondering if the user session is handled by flask-login... I know that it has a session but wasn't sure if the session was enough to keep the function (which to my knowledge isn't async unless I make it) from getting hung if one user gives it something it doesn't like...